# CSS text not changing color

Tags: html, css

So when I tried to put a white color on some text it did not change in the browser. When I user inspect on google chrome it shows that the text is "color: rgb(34, 34, 34);" When in the code I put "color:white;"

HTML:

```
<div id="features">
    <div id="features-filter"></div>
    <div id="features-text">
        <h1>Features</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#features {
    background: url("img/server-room.jpg") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    height: 70%;
    z-index: 99;
}

#features-filter {
    position: absolute;
    background: url("img/dot.png") repeat;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#features-text {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
}

#features-text h1 {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: is this all the code?

Comment: Works for me [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qsw2uskq/)

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser's cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be a caching issue.

Alternatively, there might be a rule within your CSS (or another style sheet) that defines the style of the element after you change the color to white.

When you inspect it, where is the "color: rgb(34, 34, 34);" style defined from? Is it defined from the #features-text h1 that you've written, or is it being defined by another rule, elsewhere in the stylesheet (or another stylesheet?) If it's being defined elsewhere - find out where and make sure this rule isn't overwriting the style you've defined.

Or, if it's being applied by a style sheet that you can't access/edit and you need to define it in your style sheet specifically, try using:

```
#features-text h1 {
   color: white !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well here it works try to set it important maybe something else in your code overwrites it

```css
body{background: gray;}
#features {
    background: url("img/server-room.jpg") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    height: 70%;
    z-index: 99;
}

#features-filter {
    position: absolute;
    background: url("img/dot.png") repeat;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#features-text {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
}

#features-text h1 {
    color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="features">
    <div id="features-filter"></div>
    <div id="features-text">
        <h1>Features</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it. Obviously I changed the color to blue.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <div id="features">
        <div id="features-filter"></div>
        <div id="features-text">
            <h1>Features</h1>
        </div>

    </div>
    <style>
    #features {
        background: url("img/server-room.jpg") no-repeat center;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
        height: 70%;
        z-index: 99;
    }

    #features-filter {
        position: absolute;
        background: url("img/dot.png") repeat;
        z-index: 999;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #features-text {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
    }

    #features-text h1 {
        color: blue;
    }</style>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its always better to use Hex Code instead  of color name.  This way,  you make sure every browser supports your code:

```
#features-text h1 {
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your css code in style tags, then it'll work.

```
<style>
#features {
    background: url("img/server-room.jpg") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    height: 70%;
    z-index: 99;
}

#features-filter {
    position: absolute;
    background: url("img/dot.png") repeat;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#features-text {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
}

#features-text h1 {
    color: white;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change text color by using this css code

```
 h1{
 color:#FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try hex code and add `!important`:

```
h1{
 color:#FFFFFF !important;
}
```

the hex code have a RGB value. it's like RR-GG-BB.

On normal number, it's count like this: 0123456789

You can count hex number like this: 0123456789ABCDEF